# Error de Forbidden en la exportación de más de 1000 registros

Tags: phpexcel, servidor, tcpdf

Buen día, se me presento la siguiente problemática.

Actualmente, estoy exportando registros de varias tablas de una base de datos haciendo uso de la librería PHP Excel en Codeigniter.

Mi situación es que cuando es una cantidad de registros (filas) menor a 1000, exporta la información que requiero ya sea en formato .xls o en PDF, pero cuando quiero exportar más de 1000 registros o filas, me marca el error:

```
You don't have permission to Access / on this server.
```

Ya modifiqué los permisos, algunas directivas en el .htaccess y hasta en el php.ini pero no logro dar solución a este problema.

¿Alguna solución que puedan proporcionarme?

Gracias.

Comment: Y será un tema de la cantidad de archivos o será que con algún id o nombre en particular genera algún error? Has probado empezar desde cierto registro en particular, como si tu exportación hubiese pasado de cierto punto por ejemplo?  El error es raro para ser simplemente por cantidad de registros, si fuera eso tendría que ser algún tipo de timeout... no sé cómo armas los nombres de esos archivos o sus rutas, pero podría ser que en algún o algunos archivos, al intentar guardarlos, se genera un nombre o ruta que te da conflictos.

Comment: Gracias por su respuesta, no había pensado ese aspecto.
Solo que en un servidor local la exportación la hace correctamente aún asi sobre pase los 1000 registros; solo que al subirlo a un servidor en la nube me marca este error que comento.